Time clauses and using perfect tenses
When it comes to time clauses we can use either present perfect or present simple. For example "I will do it when he arrives or has arrived" have the same meaning. Yet, when it comes to some examples I'm not sure if perfect is acceptable. Let me present these examples.
1 I was doing it when she had come
2 I will have done it when you have come
3 I will have been doing for 3 years when you have finished
4 I will not have done it before you have come
5 I will have done it after you have paid me
6 I wil have been doing it for 2 days after you have gone away
1 is wrong because we use present or past perfect to emphasize that once some action is finished another can happen and "doing it" already happened before. That's why it is incorrect and should be "I was doing it when she came".
2 I think the same explanation applies and it should be "I will have done it when you come".
3 same thing here too. It should be "I will have been doing it for 3 years when you finish".
4 seems to be wrong. I need "before you come". I am not sure if 4 is fine or wrong
5 I think simple future perfect doesn't work well with "after" and even if we changed " after you have paid me" to "after you pay me" that still would be incorrect
6 could be valid if we changed "after you have gone away" to "after you go away". The same explanation given to my first three examoles applies here tol.
Tell me if I am right, please.
Once again, I think that we are only allowed to use present perfect with time clauses when it emphasizes the completion of one event before another can happen like "I will be reach when I earn or have earned a lot". I also think that examples present by me don't have this meaning and the action happens before the completion of the second one like "I will go there before you have come". Simply I want to know if I am right that present perfect can not be used with time clauses if the sentence doesn't show the completion of once action before another happens and I gave some examples which to don't make sense with perfect to see if I am right?

This is silly. You're just combining random permutations of verb forms, with no real regard for meaning. What possible context do you have in mind to justify using when she had come in your first "sentence" rather than when she came or after she came? Explain exactly the situation you want to describe using when, while, before, after,... to link two different verb constructions, and we can tell you whether your verb forms are valid for the meaning you want. Asking us to ascribe "meaning" or "validity" to a bunch of random permutations isn't the way forward.

@FumbleFingers I presented more information

All six sentences are nonsense. Your comments on them are more or less correct except for (6). I will have been doing it for two days requires a specific point in time as the end of those two days, so only when you go away is possible.
